# Divide and Conquer to check if a value in a list is equal to its index

Tags: python, arrays, list, divide-and-conquer

Given a list of distinct integers (decreasing order), return True if there is atleast position p, such that the value at position p is p. For instance, List = [4, 3, 2, 0], the function returns true since 2 is at index 2.

I know we can just go for a loop and check if list[i] == i.

I was wondering if and how this can be implemented with the divide and conquer algorithm?

My base cases are:

- L is empty, return False.
- If L[0] is negative, return False. Since list is in decreasing order, all values will be negative, and all index are positive. SO we will not get a match. *For simplicity, i am just considering positive index.*

I am a bit confused how to divide the list here. Since splitting the list in 2, each list would have index [0:n/2]. So comparing the the values and index dont make sense.

Appreciate some help!

Comment: Not all list indices have to be positive. For your example `List = [4, 3, 2, 0]`, see what `List[-2]` gives you.

Comment: Are all the elements non-negative?

Comment: Yeah, index can be negative, but im considering only the positive ones, for simplicity. Ill add that in the question. Anyways List[-2] = 3, so it would not be true for that index.
And nope, elements can be positive or negative.

Comment: Look at the middle element of the list.  Depending on whether its value is lower or higher than its index, you know that the matching element has to be before or after that point, respectively.  Repeat until you either find the exact match, or the region of the list you're looking at is reduced to less than two elements.

Comment: but when i consider the upper part of the list, ill be comparing the middle value of the smaller list, with a "fake" index. Cause in the smaller list, the index would be [0:n/2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to compare the starting and ending values of a list to the values in the list index to see if it's possible.

**Code**

```
 def divide_conqueer(lst, indexes = None):
    
    if indexes is None:
        indexes = list(range(len(lst)))     # create list index
        
    if not lst:
        return False
    elif len(lst) == 1:
        return lst[0] == indexes[0]
    elif lst[0] < indexes[0] or lst[-1] > indexes[-1]:
        # Compare values of beginning and end of the list to the
        # list indexes of the beginnning and end
        # There is a matching value to index only if beginning value >= starting index and
        #                                            ending value <= ending index
        return False
    else:
        # Divide values and intervals in half and test each half
        return (divide_conqueer(lst[:len(lst)//2], indexes[:len(indexes)//2]) or
                divide_conqueer(lst[len(lst)//2:], indexes[len(indexes)//2:]))
```

**Test**

```
print(divide_conqueer([4, 3, 2, 1]))
# Output: True
```

Comment: this works!! 
Is there a possibility to not pass indexes in the function tho?

Comment: @zassar -- the indexes are created internally, not by the caller.  indexes are needed since it varies depending on which sublist we are working on.  Otherwise, we would not know the range of the index.

Comment: @DarryIG true, but if i were to create a function that does not use the divide and conquer, i would just pass the list. And use a loop. Thats why i asked